# intermediate page before redirect to external links

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink, external

i'm novice in php and already searched the forum for this and found something similar although i don't understand it

i have 2 external links http://www.hello.com and http://www.bye.com

on click on each link, i want to load an intermediate page (eg: redirect.php) for 5 second with a

message: "You are leaving misite.com. goodbye."

and then, make the correct to the correct external link that applies in each case.

i need:

1.- content of redirect.php

```
  <a href="<?php $hello.com = $_GET['link']; ?>">Continue to external link</a>
  <a href="<?php $link = $_GET['link']; ?>">Continue to external link</a>
```

i'm sure it's wrong. 
also, i don't know how to put a 5 seconds spinner (gif) an then make the redirection (step3)

2.- link users click on it. is it ok?
i have:

```
  <a href="http://redirect.php?link=hello.com" title="hello">hello</a>
```

not sure if it's correct
the link the users hit, tries to call the link in the redirect page, but i'm unable

well, the thing i don't know how to make it work and i really aprecciate an example
thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should make your link to redirect.php, and add the "final destination" as a URL parameter, as you have already done. On redirect.php, use a meta tag in the head section that redirects (see [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/f/what-is-a-meta-redirect.htm) for an example).

EDIT: Code requested...

In your main php page, have your links as you already wrote:

```
<a href="http://redirect.php?link=hello.com">Hello</a>
<a href="http://redirect.php?link=goodbye.com">Goodbye</a>
```

In redirect.php, you need to add a meta tag in the `<head>...</head>` section of your HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>" />
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>You are leaving my site!</h1>
        <img src="/images/spinner.gif" alt="spinner" />
    </body>
</html>
```

and that's it. The meta tag "content" attribute contains the number of seconds before redirecting, and the address to redirect to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'd rellay appreciate if you could write the code. i'm very junior

Comment: hello again, done step by step and doesn't work. ido i have to add that is an external link? i also tried changing the link to <a href="http://www.mydomain/redirect.php?link=goodbye.com">Goodbye</a>

Comment: do i have to add this in redirect.php?  <a href="<?php $link = $_GET['link']; ?>">Continue to external link</a>

Comment: i think there is something missing in redirect.php to make the redirection work

Comment: all the links return me to my homepage (it'a a wordpress) any ideas?

Comment: It must be something with wordpress then (I know nothing about it) because on my local machine, using exactly what I wrote above, it works fine. I'm guessing that Wordpress is probably rewriting the URL, then defaulting to the homepage when it doesn't find the resource. One thing I'm sure of, is that in a standard "vanilla" php environment, what I wrote above works.

Comment: thanks for the response. i thoght it's something related with rewriting url. thanks for reply :)

Comment: Inserting $_GET['link'] opens you up to major cross-site scripting vulnerabilities. You need to sanitize this input properly first.